# The constructor DefaultShardManagerBuilder() is deprecated (DefaultShardManagerBuilder builder = new DefaultShardManagerBuilder();)

Tags: java, discord-jda

**What i do wrong?**
**It says me: The constructor DefaultShardManagerBuilder() is deprecated**.
**But Why and how can i Fix it (its my first code)**

```
public class DonaldBot {
    
    public ShardManager shardMan;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            new DonaldBot();
        } catch (LoginException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public DonaldBot() throws LoginException, IllegalArgumentException {
        DefaultShardManagerBuilder builder = new DefaultShardManagerBuilder();
        builder.setToken("NzUzNjI0NzU0MDI3NjI2NTg2.X1o5vw.1oT_Hhn6FVaZf8ewIHOkrTcEU-M");
        
        builder.setActivity(Activity.watching("Chil Ecke"));
        builder.setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
        
        builder.addEventListeners(new CommandListener());
        
        
        this.shardMan = builder.build();
        System.out.println("[Donald] Bot Online.");
```

Comment: From the _javadoc_ for class [DefaultShardManagerBuilder](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/sharding/DefaultShardManagerBuilder.html#%3Cinit%3E()): _Due to breaking changes to the discord api gateway you are now required to explicitly state which events your bot needs. For this reason we have changed to new factory methods that require setting the gateway intents. Use `create(Collection)` instead._

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/sharding/DefaultShardManagerBuilder.html), "*Due to breaking changes to the discord api gateway you are now required to explicitly state which events your bot needs.*". This answers the "why" part of your question.

Regarding the "how can I fix it", I'd try `DefaultShardManagerBuilder builder = DefaultShardManagerBuilder.create(...)`.